# S3 Client connection leak after exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, connection-pooling, resource-leak, connection-leaks

I'm fairly new to AWS SDK

I am trying to get a file from S3, but that file might not exist, and apparently there is easy way to check for that with the Amazon S3 client, so I am trying to get that object anyways, and inside exception handling I check for error message.equals("noSuchKey"). (I know using exception to control such flow is not best practise but could't find a better way)

But then the problem becomes that the http pooling client causes resources to leak, and I can not find a way to close it.

Here's the code:

```
    AWSCredentials myCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(myAccessKeyID, mySecretKey);
    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(myCredentials)
    S3Object object = null;
    GetObjectRequest req = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName);

    try{
        object = s3Client.getObject(req);
        //the following line is not reached because of the exception
        InputStream objectData = object.getObjectContent();
        //do something
        //close everything 
    } catch(AmazonServiceException e){
        if(e.getErrorCode().equals("NoSuchKey")){
            //do something
            //here the 'object' is null, I don't have a reference to call close -> resource leak
        }
        else{
            DebugLog.d(e);
        }
    } catch(IOException e){
        DebugLog.d(e);
    }
```

inside the catch clause the object becomes null  so I can not really close it..nor can I close any of its input streams. The log gives me:

```
423835 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager  - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
483835 [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager  - Closing connections idle longer than 60 SECONDS
repeat..........
```

if I call this method and enter the catch clause several times, the server becomes extremely slow, which is a clear indication that each time a new PoolingClientConnectionManager is initialized, but I just can't find a way to close it

Any idea on how I can close it? Or how I can avoid using exception handling in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have "//close everything" but without posting the actual code, I can't tell if you are closing the S3Objects that were successfully loaded.  Are you sure those aren't what is being leaked?  Add a finally block to close the S3Object, or use a try-with-resouce block.  It seems that if no S3Object is found and loaded then there it can't leak.